# symmetric matrix eigenvalues real (by induction)

Tags: matrices, determinant, real-numbers

Let's say we have an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ and function $f(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. If we have some number $\lambda_0$ that is a solution to $f(\lambda)=0$, then $\lambda_0$ is a real number. I know how to solve it using the complex and complex conjugate method. The thing is that my task is to prove it using induction.
This is the proof until the point I get stuck:

We will use induction:

$1)$ n=1 $f(\lambda)=a_{11}-\lambda$. We have that $f(\lambda)$ is real and that $a_{11}$ is real and therefore $\lambda$ is real.

$2)$ Let's assume it's true for n, we'll prove it for n+1

We develop $f(\lambda_0)$ by the (n+1)-th row. Therefore $f(\lambda_0)$ = $\sum_{i=0}^n(a_{n+1,i}A_{n+1,i})$ + $(a_{n+1,n+1}-\lambda_0)A_{n+1,n+1}$=$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}(a_{n+1,i}A_{n+1,i})$-$\lambda_0 A_{n+1,n+1}$

$A_{n+1,n+1}$ is a real number using the induction assumption. We have to prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}(a_{n+1,i}A_{n+1,i})$ is a real number and therefore we'll have that $\lambda_0 \in \Bbb R$.

P.S I don't know how to make matrices in this site, so I attach a photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWCQb.jpg)

Comment: Please have a look at my edits (you can see them by clicking edit underneath your post, or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3112721/edit) and learn some MathJax formatting.

Comment: Now I don't understand the sentence " If we have some number, let's say,  is a solution, then  is a real number." First, a solution to **what**? Second, is that sentence an assumption? Do you claim that this is always true?

Comment: f(p)=0 is the equation, we have to prove that p is a real number. (It has to be true for each solution p)

Comment: This is not true unless the matrix is (for instance) symmetric, which you mention in the title but not in the question.

Comment: To prove it by induction you will probably need the fact that if $z$ is a root of a polynomial, then $\overline z$ is also a root of the polynomial. You then set up induction starting with the trivial case $n=1$ and in the induction step you use Laplace' Theorem, I would say. But using Laplace gives you only one determinant of a smaller matrix that is symmetric and further $n-1$ determinants of non-symmetric matrices.. So let me ask, how did you try to prove it?

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad. The matrix is symmetric.

Comment: I cannot edit it, so I attached a photo, it is all written there